# Excel VBA: How do I retrieve the number of named cells in a single column in a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

A number of cells in Column A in Sheet1 has an assigned unique name. What would a sub that returns the *number* of named cells look like?

Comment: Please read the FAQ and take the [Tour]. Then edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will loop through all named ranges in the workbook and check if they are intersect with Column A (or whatever you define checkRange to be).  I actually had a hard time selecting named ranges specific to a single worksheet.  This will also count named ranges that have any cell in Column A but that may be larger than that.

Public Sub CountNamedRanges()
    On Error Resume Next

```
Dim namedRangeCount As Long
Dim nameCollection As Names
Dim v As Variant
Dim n As Name
Dim nameRange As Range      'The range of the specific namedRange
Dim checkRange As Range     'The range you wish to see if it contains the named range

namedRangeCount = 0

'This is the range where we are counting named ranges
Set checkRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

Set nameCollection = ThisWorkbook.Names         'This actually didn't work when I tried to retrieve this same property for only a single worksheet
If (nameCollection.Count > 0) Then
    For Each v In nameCollection
        Set n = v
        If InStr(1, n.RefersTo, "#REF", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then        'You need this in case the named range is deleted and becomes #N/A
            Set nameRange = n.RefersToRange
            'See if the named range intersects with the check range and if so, increment the counter
            If (Application.Intersect(nameRange, checkRange)) Then
                namedRangeCount = namedRangeCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next v
End If

MsgBox "There are " & namedRangeCount & " named ranges in the checkRange"
```

End Sub

Comment: Many thanks AceAlan for the effort but your code delivers the wrong number of named ranges. I have 30+ named ranges in Column A, where each name corresponds to a single cell, but your namedRangeCount variable returns "20".